# How do I train the object detection model with negative samples?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

The model detects the object of interest fine but also wrongly detects similar looking objects.

So my question is threefold:

- How do I train the model with negative examples to avoid these false positives?
- Do I add another class for each similar looking object or do I throw them all into with "others" class?
- Or do I just have to include images that include both object of interest and the similar looking objects and the model should be able to do that on its own?

Comment: I reformatted the question for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, adding images with similar looking objects but not labeling them should work.

Comment: Thank you. I'd just like to clarify, do these similar looking objects have to be in the same images with the annotated objects of interest or can i just populate the train set with images of similar looking objects without annotations?

Comment: Both of what you described should be ok.